# Can't open website on Android chrome

Tags: security-certificate, google-chrome, android

I created web site and from computer it works. But we have problem on android google chrome. error

"Your connection is private" ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID.

any idea? please help.

Comment: rly? go to advanced in bottom left and get yourself in page?

Answer (score 1):

Ok problem is in certificate. I used [ssl checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.htm) and got error so now I know what to do

The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by following Comodo's Certificate Installation Instructions for your server platform (use these instructions for InstantSSL). Pay attention to the parts about Intermediate certificates.

Comment: Your link is missing an 'l' at the end, should be: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Answer (score 0):

Is your system date/time ok (Both server and phone)? The error code states "DATE INVALID"

It could also be an antivirus which thinks something is wrong with your certificate and somehow triggers a wrong error message

Comment: Yes I know that date must be same. also antivirus can cause this problem. Dates are same. It works from any pc. But I have problem from mobile devices.